# Speeding up conversion from Byte-String to Image after getting the String from TCP Client in Python

Tags: python, string, image, opencv, numpy

I have a Client that recieves an image from a TCP Server in a TCP Client.

After this the Image is serialized and of course as bytes. Now I want to to reshape this again into an image.

However my process takes really long so I was wondering if there is maybe a more pythonic,faster way of doing so ?

The code is commented for each step, but here they are:

1.Convert it from hex binary representation to a readable string (0.002 s)

2.Split up the string after each byte couple (0.08 s)

3.Cast each value of the list to integer (0.17 s)

4.Reshape into matrix representation for red,green,blue (0.02)

5.Reshape Matrices together to form image

After looking at timings I found out that the most time is taking by step 3.

```
#....Some TCP stuff before, and this code is in a loop:
#Convert from hex binary to string
asstr = binascii.hexlify(data)
#Split up after each byte couple
n = 2
split = [asstr[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(asstr), n)]
#Convert each byte couple to integer from its hex representation    
asint = [];
for i in split:    
    asint.append(int(i,16))   

#Reshape into red,green and blue
try:
    red = np.asarray(asint[::3]).reshape(240,424);
    green = np.asarray(asint[1::3]).reshape(240,424);
    blue = np.asarray(asint[2::3]).reshape(240,424);
except ValueError:
    continue;

#Reshape into an Image representation for opencv
img = np.transpose(np.asarray([red,green,blue],dtype=np.uint8),axes=(1, 2, 0))

#Show image
cv2.imshow('something',img)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

If I print out data I get some "ascii-crap" in the command line which are just representations of their numbers in ascii. 
After decoding them with `binascci.hexlify(data)` and printing it out I get the values as one huge string like "`0112311a3b2b1c312...`" (just an example)

Comment: So, which step is taking most of the time/which part is the bottleneck?

Comment: The step 3 as I now found out

Comment: Maybe you could do the `int` conversion in the previous step itself : `[int(asstr[i:i+n],16) for i in range(0, len(asstr), n)]`?

Comment: Thank you, this made a little bit of improvement: Step 2 now takes ~ 0.21 seconds - which in overall is faster but still too slow

Comment: Sorry if this is a daft question but what exactly is the point of steps 1-3? If I'm not mistaken you are converting bytes (essentially numbers) to hex strings and then back to numbers. Couldn't you cut out this back-and-forth? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not making things way more complicated than necessary? Maybe I'm missing something, but with a mock `bytes` object of the correct length I get the same output as your five-step method in a single line:

```
import numpy as np
import binascii

def the_humourless_route(data):
    return np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(240, 424, 3)

def the_scenic_route(data):
    #....Some TCP stuff before, and this code is in a loop:
    #Convert from hex binary to string
    asstr = binascii.hexlify(data)
    #Split up after each byte couple
    n = 2
    split = [asstr[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(asstr), n)]
    #Convert each byte couple to integer from its hex representation    
    asint = [];
    for i in split:    
        asint.append(int(i,16))   

    #Reshape into red,green and blue
    try:
        red = np.asarray(asint[::3]).reshape(240,424);
        green = np.asarray(asint[1::3]).reshape(240,424);
        blue = np.asarray(asint[2::3]).reshape(240,424);
    except ValueError:
        pass

    #Reshape into an Image representation for opencv
    img = np.transpose(np.asarray([red,green,blue],dtype=np.uint8),axes=(1, 2, 0))
    return img

data = bytes(np.random.randint(0, 256, (240*424*3,)).tolist())
print(np.all(the_scenic_route(data) == the_humourless_route(data)))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thank you this worked really nice! I did not know about the "frombuffer" method from numpy